# Tweetdeck Add Home Column dialog missing Twitter handle field

Tags: firefox, twitter

I'm wanting to add a Home Column for another Twitter account (not one of mine) to Tweetdeck. I've tried following the instructions such as [here](http://metro.co.uk/2016/01/05/heres-how-to-tell-if-someone-has-muted-you-on-twitter-5602894/) and [here](http://support.twitter.com/articles/20169914#), but the Add Home Column dialog that comes up does not have the field to enter a Twitter handle shown in the top left of the screen shot on the first link.

This is what I see:

[image]

I'm using the very latest Firefox (50.0.1).

Is this functionality still available, or am I missing something?